# Bulk copy from one server to another server

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlbulkcopy, bulk

I have table contains 5 million records and one of its column contains PDF data in blob column. I want to move this table records from one  server into another  Server.

I tried below methods.

1. Import and Export wizard
2. Linked server.

But it is taking some time.So any other bulk copy method or commands to transfer this table records from one server to another server quickly.

Comment: Maybe you need a tool like to RH  https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse

Comment: Please don't use Indian numbering system here. It's going to confuse people that what are "lakh records". Also, "some time" doesn't mean anything to us. Please use some sort of clear measurements. Is that 5 minutes? 5 hours? something else?